# My Chart is Cut Off When Drawn (Most of The Time)

Tags: mschart

I'm filling an mschart with data dynamically, and most of the time the chart is cut off on the right.

[image]

I've been fiddling with many of the properties on the x axis and the chart area, but nothing seems to fix it. For these charts when I stretch the form across both of my monitors the chart will eventually fit. And yet, it will fit no problem for data that's very similar.

I'm not terribly well versed in mschart, is it a problem with the chart area or the x axis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to play with the Width property of your ChartArea, try setting it to something between 75-100. Also can I check if the label to the left 'Count' is Axis Title or a text drawn using Title object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Count is the Y Axis title which I assume means that it isn't the problem. As for your other suggestion I don't see Width as a part of the ChartArea properties. Do you mean the Width in the Position or InnerPlotPosition properties?

Comment: Yes, I meant Position.Width. That is how the width of ChartArea is controlled. If this doesn't help, please provide with some code snippet on the properties which have applied to chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an incorrect assumption that the lack of the vertical line on the end meant that part of the chart was hidden. The fix was to specify the interval with which to label the axis so a label is always drawn at the end.